# CSS resize | Speed up rate of change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

The CSS `resize` property is a convenient way to add a grip to a div so that the user can resize it, with minimal coding. Unfortunately, I'm finding that the rate of change when resizing is horribly slow and not at all a pleasant experience as a user. Is there a way to modify the rate of change with the `resize` property?

Or is the only real way to gain control over it to use a scripting solution?

Thanks!

```css
.resizable {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200;
  height: 500;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="resizable">
  <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/b/ba/Goku_anime_profile.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's odd. Please may you share a [mcve] using the `<>` button? In my experience it is a 1:1 mouse movement. Are you sure you don't have a transition css property on it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Now that I take a closer look, it does appear to be 1:1 (I'll adjust the problem description). I really want to know if there's a way to adjust the rate of change because it just feels sluggish. It also jumps when I initially grab the grip, causing it to shrink temporarily.

Comment: Tried the example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize#using_resize_with_arbitrary_elements) in a code block and it does indeed work on stackoverflow.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added a simple example above. I find the resizing to not feel quite right, particularly when resizing vertically. I'd like to know if there are any setting that can smooth out the experience.

Comment: I cannot share your assessment. It works perfectly.

Comment: I can reproduce the bad UX when the image is larger than the viewport (size change gets slow in FF, and too fast in Chromiums). Resizing becomes laggy in the direction of viewport scrollbar(s), when no scrollbars, the element resizes fine. Setting `overflow: hidden` for the resizable element helps a bit, but I'm not sure if you can entirely get rid of this behavior with such large images, if you need to keep static/relative position of the resizable element. Setting `position: absolute` for it makes resizing fluent despite of the outer scrollbars.